# Using dynamic ranges with EPPlus

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I need this kind of code :

```
// sheet.Cells is an ExcelRange
sheet.Cells["A1:E1"].Merge = true;
```

to be dynamic, with a base reference point :

```
private void CreateSection(ExcelRange basePosition)
{
    // sheet.Cells is an ExcelRange
    // E.g. if basePosition.Address is "A1", then dynamic value would be "A1:E1"
    // E.g. if basePosition.Address is "C4", then dynamic value would be "C4:G4"
    sheet.Cells["{basePosition.Address}:{basePosition.Address+4cols}"].Merge = true;
}
```

How can I construct such an index for using with `sheet.Cells`, from the `basePosition`?

Comment: Can you instead use the overload on numbers ? sheet.Cells[FromRow, FromCol, ToRow, ToCol].Merge = true ?

Comment: @andrew oh I will try thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd choose to use the `.Offset()` function for this. It's nice and neat and saves calculating which row/col indexes you need for the new range.

So something like this would give a range 5 rows down and 1 column wide from your original `basePosition`:

```cs
private static void CreateSection(ExcelRange basePosition)
{
    var rangeToMerge = basePosition.Offset(0, 0, 5, 1);
    rangeToMerge.Merge = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks elegant. For my case, I think I would need `.Offset(0, 0, 1, 5)`